# Can I run The Old Republic without an Administrator account?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

*Stupidly long story short...*

I have access to Windows 7 computer that I can only log into with a "Guest" account.  The Guest account does not have Administrator access.

Star Wars: The Old Republic is already installed, and in fact there is a shortcut on the desktop; however, attempting to run it prompts me for an Administrator password. I do know someone who is an Administrator, but I don't want to bother her every time I want to run the game.

Can I play Star Wars: The Old Republic on this machine, and if so how? I am willing to have the Administrator set something up (a shortcut or something), just so long as I can run it without her help.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate (as this is probably why it's asking): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42747/how-do-i-stop-the-launcher-bringing-up-the-uac-prompt-every-time

Comment: @Nick Not really the same question. Looks like the UAC prompt happens, even on Admin accounts, if you have UAC on. That's not the issue, here, though they are related - looks like the solution might end up being the same. What a pain!

Comment: @MagRoader: They are exactly the same reasons. Remember, even on Admin accounts, programs are launched with User rights. A program that pops a UAC on an Admin account will also pop a UAC on an User account **and vice versa**.

Comment: I posted an answer to [How do I stop the launcher bringing up the UAC prompt every time?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/153365/61492) that I have tested on windows 8.1

Answer (score 15):

Technically, yes but it's a bit of a hassle to set up.

You'll need to use Microsoft's Application Compatibility Toolkit to apply shims to the launcher.

1. First, download and install both the [Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7352) and the [Application verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=20028).
2. Run the Compatibility Toolkit's *Standard User Analyzer Wizard* . It is located in Start Menu > Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit > Developer and Tester Tools
3. Enter the location (or browse for) the launcher. It should be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Electronic Arts\BioWare\Star Wars-The Old Republic`
4. Click **Launch**
5. Very Important: You should see 2 LUA Prompts: the first for the Standard User Analyser and the Second for the SWTOR Launcher. Accept the first but decline the second.
6. The Analyser will ask whether the application ran without problems. The launcher should not have launched (If it did, you may have accepted the LUA prompt I said to decline earlier). Click **No**
7. The Analyser will suggest some mitigations. You *should* only need to check *Force Administrator Access* (*), but if you want to be sure or if it doesn't work the first time, you can check them all; it will only loosen some security in a few extremely specific folders/registry keys. That should not cause any problem in an environment that allows you to play SWTOR.
8. Click "Launch" to test the settings.
9. The launcher should have launched properly without any prompts. If it didn't, click no and select somemore mitigations in step 7.
10. Once the launcher works properly, Click **Yes** then **Export** to create an msi file containing your fixes.
11. Run the generated MSI to install the shims permanently.

There is one last step to take care of every last prompt. In the `extras` folder of your SWTOR installation  (so `C:\Program Files (x86)\Electronic Arts\BioWare\Star Wars-The Old Republic\extras`), there should be a file named `vc2008redist_x86.exe`. Rename it to `vc2008redist_x86.exe.unused`

> (*) Despite the name, this shim does not give Administrator access to the launcher without your knowledge; it lies to the launcher telling it you are an Administrator when in fact you are **not**

Comment: If anyone want to try to skip to step 11, [here's my msi](http://www.mediafire.com/?c2m64oms0r133ry). I'm not making any promises to whether or not it'll work (For starters, I installed SWTOR on my D drive), but if it can save someone some time, then great.

Comment: This is a more detailed version of my answer. Excellent work. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42747/how-do-i-stop-the-launcher-bringing-up-the-uac-prompt-every-time

Comment: Thank you for this detailed guide. At step 7 I unchecked everything except "Force Administrator access" and it worked for me. But i'm wondering about this vc2008redist_x86.exe. Maybe someone can tell me why it does even exists if it isn't needed.

Comment: It is technically needed, but only once. It's the installer for the  Visual Vtudio redistributable dlls. Ideally, it'd only need to be installed once, but for some reason Bioware runs it on every launch.

Comment: For me, the default settings *didn't* work. But using just "Force Administrator access" did work.

Comment: Good to know. That's what my installer sets too. I'll edit once my supper's ready

Comment: I recently installed the game and there is no vc2008redist_x86.exe file.  Not sure if this is because I downloaded the free to play version, I already had it installed (since I play a number of games that require it) or if they fixed the bug.

Comment: For those more technical minded, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766024(v=ws.10).aspx indicates that the resulting shim will intercept API calls by the program to the extent that the program will think that it is running with administrative access.  In the event that administrative access is required you will probably get an error in which case you would need to restart as admin.  I expect this would never be needed since the MMO already has full access to its files.

Comment: Recently the launcher changed and the old shims stopped matching/working, I tried to recreate them on windows 10 and it isn't possible, what I did was to update my swtor on the windows 7 computer, create the msi there and copy+install it in the windows 10 system, worked perfectly. [r15ch13 method](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/299371/194342) also works on windows 10, I just didn't want to keep the program installed

Answer (score 1):

I successfully run the program using Compatibility Mode for Windows 2000.

Find `launcher.exe` and go to the program Properties (Right-click > Properties) > Compatibility tab. There, check the `Run this program in compatibility mode for:` box, and select `Windows 2000` in the Drop-down.

My specific information: I'm running Windows 7 without UAC (on a non-administrator account, of course), and installed to a location outside of my Program Files directory.

I have also verified that this does not show the UAC prompt when using UAC.

Comment: This still needs to be tested properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully gotten the loader to work by first trying out the above method of changing the compatibility mode to that of Windows 2000 but it failed.  So I then did the following:

From the Administrator account I right clicked the Star Wars KOTR icon and then I choose the option for Troubleshoot Compatibility.  It will open up a small window, simply run the option for troubleshooting it in Windows XP service pack 2, then in the following window click on the start program button to test the loader and it should open the SW login window and you should be good, close out the login window and then click next and then click on the first option to save the settings and your all set!

Hope this helps anyone out that may be having the login issue with SW KOTR UAC error with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to install the game somewhere that doesn't require special permissions to access.  (Note that the existing install folder can simply be moved, since SWTOR is completely self-contained.)

For example, I have my game installed to my secondary drive (`D:\SWTOR`) which has the Full Access permission granted for the `System` user and the `Everyone` group.  You could have the Administrator apply these permissions to only the SWTOR folder as well (and remove any limiting permissions from it also).

Comment: This does not work with SWTOR.  I installed the game into a folder where everyone has full access, and it still requires admin permissions.

Comment: @Trisped Interesting, it works for me.  I have Win8, are you using a different version?

Comment: I tried it with Windows 7 and Windows 10.